# Load Image With AJAX (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, ajax, image, loading

i have this script:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/get.php?id=' + c + '&type=1',
    dataType: "html"
}).done(function (a) {
    $(".playerr:eq(" + b + ")").html(a).show()
});
```

how can i add an loading image ?

Comment: my entire function is this :  var pml = -1;    function showpl(b, c, d) {
    if (pml != -1) $(".playerr:eq(" + pml + ")").html('').hide();
    var b = $("." + d).index(b);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/get.php?id=' + c + '&type=1',
        dataType: "html"
    }).done(function (a) {
        $(".playerr:eq(" + b + ")").html(a).show()
    });
    pml = b;
    return false
}

Answer (score 1):

You can use `beforeSend` and `success` or done to show and hide the loading image

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: '/get.php?id=' + c + '&type=1',
    dataType: "html"
}).done(function (a) {
    $(".playerr:eq(" + b + ")").html(a).show();
    $("#img1").hide();
}).beforeSend(function(){
      $("#img1").show();
});
```

Comment: You can hide the image on .done() so even in case of error the image will be hidden, else it will keep on  showing.

Comment: Not working is not clear statement, do you get beforeSend and done event?

Comment: image is not appear and all requests appear in first div